# Applications and system keep crashing randomly

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 19.04, crash, system

As the title says, my applications keep crashing at random times when I use them. With Firefox and Chrome, usually just one tab at a time crashes randomly, but sometimes the whole browser will crash too. The whole system itself may crash every once in a while. The system was installed from an 18.04 disk, which was used on another computer that is working fine. I've since upgraded to 19.04 in hopes of that somehow fixing the issue but it persists. What do I do? What sort of information do you need?

swapon -s outputs the following:

```
Filename                                Type        Size    Used  Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition   9838588 0     -2
```

Comment: We need you to help us help you by providing more information. Please run `swapon -s` then  click [edit] and add the results to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that you are routinely observing the "Hold up! Google Chrome has slammed" message, there is likely an issue on your framework. An incidental accident can occur, however, customary accidents are presumably brought about by something you can fix. 
On the off chance that you are interested exactly how frequently Chrome is smashing, you can type chrome://collides with your area bar and press Enter to see a rundown of accidents and when they happened. This is only one of Chrome's many shrouded chrome://pages.

**Expansions and Add-ons**

These things are exceptionally valuable however Chrome regularly gets shaky because of various program expansions, modules, or additional items. In spite of the fact that it is anything but an extremely fulfilling arrangement, keeping just 2-3 additional items in the Chrome program can enormously lessen the recurrence of Chrome crashes. Have a go at decreasing the number of augmentations and additional items you are as of now utilizing and you will see the change.

**Incapacitate the clashing modules in Chrome**

Presently we are discussing a Module which is a key segment of any application. It contains a string of programming techniques that are fundamental for the run-time of uses. On the off chance that these modules are causing issues, at that point you get Chrome crashes accordingly. To recognize these issues, type chrome://clashes in the 'Address Bar'. The program will at that point load all the modules and furthermore distinguish the defective ones, permitting you to incapacitate them. It will likewise make reference to the hazardous application or augmentation alongside the modules.

Accordingly, it is ideal to uninstall or expel such clashes from your framework by utilizing 'Include or Remove Program' work in 'Charge Panel'. Like it, you can uninstall the clashing expansions from Google Chrome.

**Fix the Chrome client profile information**

Numerous reasons cause Google Chrome's client profile information to get defiled. Chrome should be shut before closing down Windows since it needs to spare the information in the client profile. On the off chance that Chrome can't refresh client profile because of an unforeseen shutdown, at that point it can harm or degenerate the unsaved information which at last causes an issue. To fix this issue, open 'Document Explorer' and check 'Concealed things' under the 'View' tab. Close Chrome on the off chance that it is open and, at that point get to the Chrome client profile envelope by following this registry:

C:\Users\youraccount\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data (your account speaks to the name of your Microsoft account)

Right-snap to 'Rename' the organizer 'Default' to anything like Default_1, Default_bkup, and so forth. That is truly it. Test it by re-opening your program.

**Impair the Sandbox security briefly**

Chrome runs a security instrument considered Sandbox that ensures the rendering of HTML and JavaScript from vindictive projects. It creates a controlled and limited condition around Chrome to ensure your working framework for getting harmed. Handicapping the Sandbox highlight has worked for certain individuals however it isn't suggested by most. Right-click the Chrome symbol and open the 'Properties' to make changes. Under the Shortcut tab, you will see a way composed in a 'Target' box. Press space toward the finish of the content, simply include - no-sandbox and snap OK.

**Clear history, treats, and other perusing information**

A generally normal and simple arrangement is much of the time cleaning the perusing information put away in Chrome. Open the Chrome menu by tapping the cheeseburger button or the three-lines symbol on the upper right of the program and open 'Settings'. At the base of the Settings page click 'Show propelled settings' and under Privacy heading click 'Content Settings' first. At that point, under Cookies heading, select the alternative that says 'Keep neighborhood information just until you quit your program' and snap OK. This permits Chrome to consequently clear the treats.

Also, click 'Clear Browsing Data' which is directly adjacent to 'Content Settings' and select all choices with the exception of 'Passwords'. This permits you to stay marked in your sites or internet based life accounts.

Source: [Google Chrome Keeps Crashing](http://www.numberforhelp.com/blog/google-chrome-keeps-crashing)